# How to process SharePoint 2010 publishing page content before rendering?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In SharePoint 2010 is there a way to process the content of a Publishing Page before it is displayed? I would like to use "shortcodes" (eg: [tab], [accordion]), in the content, then parse it into html before it is rendered to the page.

Answer (score 1):

This [site](http://the-north.com/sharepoint/post/Overriding-Sharepoint-Page-Render-method) may point you in the right direction. He created a master page with a code behind.  You could possibly creaet a custom publishing page with a code behind file that alters the contents of your page.